# Calculations not working in Multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do a program which would change all elements between first and              the biggest numbers of each array columns into 0.
The programs works, but I'm getting wrong results.

This is input file:

```
3 5
2 3 5
1 2 4
4 1 3
6 1 2
5 8 1
```

This is the result file:

```
2 0 0 6 5 
3 0 0 0 8 
5 4 3 2 1
```

But i'm expecting the result like this:

```
 2 3 5
 0 0 4
 0 0 3
 6 0 2
 5 8 1
```

I'm not sure if my code reads/prints information wrongly or I'm not understanding multidimensional array (i'm beginner in coding). Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, m, Z[100][100];

  ifstream fr("input.txt");
  ofstream fd("output.txt");

  fr >> n >> m;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      fr >> Z[i][j];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int max = Z[0][0];
    int NR = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (Z[i][j] > max) {
        max = Z[i][j];
        NR = j;
      }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < NR; j++) {
      Z[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fd << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      fd << Z[i][j] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap m and n, refer below

```
fr >> m >> n;
```

Edit:

This is your code

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
int max = Z[0][0];
int NR = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
  if (Z[i][j] > max) {
    max = Z[i][j];
    NR = j;
  }
}

for (int j = 1; j < NR; j++) {
  Z[i][j] = 0;
}
}
```

Instead it should be:

```
for(int j = 0; j < m ; j++)
{
int max = Z[0][0];
int NR = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        if(Z[i][j] > max)
        {
        max = Z[i][j];
        NR = i;
        }
    }

        for(int i = 1 ; i < NR ; i++)
        {
            Z[i][j] = 0;
        }
}
```

You are finding maximum from every row, you need to find from every column.

Comment: This only fixed the printing problem ,but now code doesn't change the numbers between first and maximum array's collums into 0. tried swapping n with m  ,but it doesn't change the result. Any reason why that is not working?

Comment: @Duona try to swap `NR = j` by  `NR = i` and fo the same with the for loop below.